# Select consumers before publishing a message rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq, messaging, soa, nosql

I am trying to build a system where I need to select next available and suitable consumer to send a message from a queue (or may be any other solution not using the queue)

**Requirements**
We have multiple publishers/clients who would send objects (images) to process on one side and multiple Analysts who would process them, once processed the publisher should get the corresponding response.

The publishers do not care which Analyst is going to process the data.

Users have a web app where they can map each client/publisher to one or more or all agents, say for instance if Publisher P1 is mapped to Agents A & B, all objects coming from P1 can be processed by Agent A or Agent B. Note: an object can only be processed by one agent only.

Depending on the mapping I should have a middleware which consumes the messages from all publishers and distributes to the agents

**Solution 1**
My initial thoughts were to have a queue where all publishers post their messages. Another queue where Agents publish message saying they are waiting to process an object.

A middleware picks the message, gets the possible list of agents it can send the message to (from cached database) and go through the agents queue to find the next suitable and available agent and publish the message to that agent.

The issue with this solution is if I have agents queue like  a,b,c,d  and the message I receive can only be processed by agent b I will be rejecting agents d & c and they would end up at the tail of the queue and I have around 180 agents so they might never be picked or if the next message can only be processed by agent d (for example) we have to reject all the agents to get there

**Solution 2**
First bit from publishers to middleware is still the same

Have a scaled fast nosql database where agents add a record to notify there availability. Basically a key value pair

The middleware gets config from cache and gets the next available + suitable agent from the nosql database sends message to the agent's queue (through direct exchange) and updates the nosql to set isavailable false ad gets the next message.

Issue with this solution is the db and middleware can become a bottleneck, also if I scale the middleware I will end up in database concurrency issues for example f I have two copies of middleware running and each recieves a message which can be proceesed by Agents A & B and both agents are available.
The two middleware copies would query the db and might get A as availble and end up sneding both messages to A while B is still waiting for a message to process.

I will have around 100 publishers and 180 agents to start with.

Any ideas how to improve these solutions or any other feasible solution would be highly appreciated?

Depending on this I also need to figure out how the Agent would send response back to the publisher.

Thank you

Comment: when you say "publisher" and "agent", are you talking about software or people?

Comment: Publisher is a software, an agent is a human who would ultimately get this image on screen and woul ddo a button click to initiate the process

Comment: the attempts at answering this prove it is **too broad** as well as **primarily opinion based**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since the total number of senders and receivers are only hundreds, how about to create one queue for each of your senders. Based on your sender receiver mapping, receivers subscribes to the sender queues (update the subscribing on mapping changes). You could configure your receiver to only receive the next message from all the queues it subscribes (in a random way) when it finishes processing one message.

Comment: Hi Teddy, thank you for the response. Hundreads of publishers was an example and is just phase 1 of the project, once done it would expand to thousands so not sure a queue per sender would be feasible.

Comment: If number of senders will be thousands, then one queue for each sender should not be acceptable. One solution is, try to group your receivers and maintian your mapping between senders and receiver groups. Thus each group of receivers could share a receiver queue. When sending messages, you could use direct or topic exchange, and senders reads mapping configure and specify the group key as routing key.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer this from the perspective the perspective of my open-source service bus: [Shuttle.Esb](http://shuttle.github.io/shuttle-esb/)

Typically one would ignore any *content-based routing* and simply have a distributor pattern.  All message go to the primary endpoint and it will distribute the messages.  However, if you decide to stick to these logical groupings you could have primary endpoints for each logical grouping (per agent group).  You would still have the primary endpoint but instead of having worker endpoints mapped to agents you would have agent groupings map to the logical primary endpoint with workers backing *that*.

Then in the primary endpoint you would, based on your content (being the agent identifier), forward the message to the relevant logical primary endpoint.  All the while you keep track of the original sender.  In the worker you would then send a message back to the queue of the original sender.

I'm sure you could do pretty much the same using any service bus.

Comment: Hi Eben, thank you for the response. To start with we would have atleast 180 workers and would grow eventually. Grouping could be any combination so we might end up with 2exp180 number of end points which probably is not feasible?

Comment: You may have to rethink your design.  180 workers is quite a bit.  Your combinations are still going to be 2exp180 even without the physical endpoints.  If that is still feasible then you *could* move the content-based distribution forward to the primary endpoint.  Your distribution logic, and keeping track of available workers, is going to take some leg-work.  I still think, though, that it is going to be less when using a service bus.

Comment: Hi @Eben you may be right I might have to rethink on my design but honestly I am out of ideas at the moment. 2exp180 could be worst case most of the times an object can be processed by any agent which should be fine (drop the message in a queue and all agents consume from it), however I need combinations to be supported, may be queue is not my option but as I said I am out of ideas at the moment

Answer (score 0):

I see several requirements in here, that can be boiled down to a few things, I think:

- publisher does not care which agent processes the image
- publisher needs to know when the image processing is done
- agent can only process 1 image at a time
- agent can only process certain images

are these assumptions correct? did I miss anything important?

if not, then your solution is pretty much built into RabbitMQ with routing and queues. there should be no need to build custom middle-tier service to manage this.

With RabbitMQ, you can have a consumer set to only process 1 message at a time. The consumer sets it's "prefetch" limit to 1, and retrieves a message from the queue with "no ack" set to `false` - meaning, it must acknowledge the message when it is done processing it.

To consume only messages that a particular agent can handle, use RabbitMQ's routing capabilities with multiple queues. The queues would be created based on the type of image or some other criteria by which the consumers can select images.

For example, if there are two types of images: TypeA and TypeB, you would have 2 queues - one for TypeA and one for TypeB.

Then, if Agent1 can only handle TypeA images, it would only consume from the TypeA queue. If Agent2 can handle both types of images, it would consume from both queues.

To put the right images in the right queue, the publisher would need to use the right routing key. If you know if the image type (or whatever the selection criteria is), you would change the routing key on the publisher side to match that selection criteria. The routing in RabbitMQ would be set up to move messages for TypeA into the TypeA queue, etc.

The last part is getting a response on when the image is done processing. That can be accomplished through RabbitMQ's "reply to" field and related code. The gist of it is that the publisher has it's own exclusive queue. When it publishes a message, it includes the name of it's exclusive queue in the "reply to" header of the message. When the agent finishes processing the image, it sends a status update message back through the queue found in the "reply to" header. That status update message tells the producer the status of the request.

From a RabbitMQ perspective, these pieces can be put together using the examples and documentation found here:

http://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html

Look at these specifically:

- Work Queues: http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html
- Topics: http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-python.html
- RPC (aka Request/Response): http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-python.html

You'll find examples in many languages, in these docs.

I also cover most of these scenarios (and others) in [my RabbitMQ Patterns eBook](https://leanpub.com/rmq-patterns)

Comment: Thank you for your time and the reply. All the assumptions are correct, in addition to that there is an external application which users can use to decide images coming from which publisher can be processed by subset of agents, depending on that configuration we need to distribute the images, hence the middleware which based on publisher to agent mapping distributes messages. The main problem is to find next available + suitable agent?

Comment: if you have configuration (set by a user or otherwise) to say which images can be processed by which agent, then that information should be used as the routing key as i mentioned above. the question of finding the next suitable agent is handled by the queue and having agents set their prefetch limit, as noted